# Mockito notNull required for inferred annotation

Tags: java, mockito, junit5, stubbing, notnull

I'm struggling to stub a method where IntelliJ creates an inferred annotation not null on the parameter:

```
 public final boolean isGlobalMatchCriteria(GlobalStore global) {
        return global.getMessage() != null );
    }
```

i tried to stub it this way, i also tried to replace notNull with more accurate any() :

```
when(manager.isGlobalMatchCriteria(notNull())).thenReturn(true);
```

Where manager is a Component that i mock.

```
@MockBean
 GlobalStoreManager manager;
```

I keep having this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "xxx.store.GlobalStore.getMessage()" because "global" is null
```

I don't understand why is it blocking on this potential null. I even called :

```
Objects.requireNonNull(global);
```

But it doesn't pass the stubbing. The execution stops on the when().thenReturn() method.

I don't get what's going on here.

Edit : changed the name of the manager for clarity.

Comment: What is `performanceStoreConverterManager`? A spy? A mock?

Answer (score 0):

The method is final...  And stubbing doesn't work on final method. As it's code legacy and i don't know why it's final... I deleted the final XD And it works like a charm.

Edit : I really struggled on this one as the Mockito error was really misleading.